# How to submit a Form on ENTER and redirect to a different route without a Submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I have an `input` tag of `type="text"` that I **don't** want to have a **submit button** for. I want it to be "submitted" for when the user presses ENTER, and when they press enter it should redirect them to a different page that I already have set up to reroute to.

I don't know how to "submit" an input tag on "enter" and then reroute the page on "enter." Any ideas?

Comment: Just put it in a `<form onSubmit={...}>`. Rerouting is a different problem you need to look up separately, and please check for existing answers before posting another question.

Comment: Most browsers will let you submit the form of single input field on hitting ENTER in field. But it is best to keep a `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` button. If you don't want to show it, hide it with CSS.

Comment: ```Enter``` or ```Return``` key ascii code is 13 if i remember well, So i believe it is possible to use it in ```onKeyPress``` prop. Need test.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which key pressed, I tested it in codeSandBox and no Ascii code check need, like this:

```js
      <input type="text"
        onKeyPress={e=>e.key==='Enter' && alert ('enter pressed')}
      />
```

Comment: @ChrisG What is wrong?

Comment: Oh You mean if input element wrapped with ```form``` element, the form will automatically submit on enter key press?

Comment: Better to wrap the input field in `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> ...`, it will make you submit the form on press of Enter. It will work with multiple fields too.